# creating custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I Know this question is asked again and again here, but did not find any solutions for my problem.I'm creating a Custom UITableViewCell through xib and trying to load it.in my VC called **ACSummaryVC**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    AcSummaryCell *cell = (AcSummaryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AcSummaryCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

**AcSummaryCell** is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`and it has an `UILabel` IBOutlate called acLabel.when i compile the project i get following error-

```
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ACSummaryVC 0x71465c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key acLabel.'`
```

i have created connection of acLabel in AcSummayCell class, but i'm getting error from ACSummaryVC? What i'm doing wrong?

**Edit:-** according to Mani's answer bellow i'm connecting outlate to file owner and it is wrong instead i've to connect outlate to custom cell.but when i try this i did not get my outlate to connect with instead i'm getting like this image -
[image]

**Now question is How to connect my outlate with custom cell?**
here is my AcSummayCell.h

```
@interface AcSummayCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel* acLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel* namelbl;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel* cBalancelbl;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel* avBalancelbl;
```

and AcSummayCell.m

```
#import "AcSummayCell.h"

@implementation AcSummayCell
@synthesize acLabel = _acLabel;
@synthesize namelbl = _namelbl;
@synthesize cBalancelbl = _cBalancelbl;
@synthesize avBalancelbl = _avBalancelbl;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you set custom class in xib as ACSummayCell?

Comment: Yes, i did. and tried with delete and re create connection/xib etc..but no luck.

Comment: Check that everything is well connected or you don't have wrong references on your xib file.

Comment: check acLabel is properly connected or not?

Comment: I did that and even recreate my UITabelViewCell subclass and xib.. the strange thing for me is that i'm creating connection in AcSummaryCell and getting error for ACSummaryVC.

Comment: have u seen it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760803/problem-with-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant

Comment: For your custom `UITabelViewCell` have you mentioned your class in xib?

Comment: Where have you declared `acLabel`?

Comment: where is property for your label...???

Comment: I've edited my question please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have setup a wrong outlet connection. Its because you have connected your label's outlet to your file's owner. Remove that label outlet connection out of file's owner and connect the outlet pointing to your custom cell. It should work.

Comment: Can you please explain it because when i'm trying to connect to custom cell it did not show my outlate to connect instead it shows accessoryView, backgroundView etc.

Comment: Check whats the class you have selected in your Identity Inspector of XIB. It should be your custom tableviewcell's class name (in your case, AcSummayCell). Click on the File's Owner in your XIB and open up the identity inspector and change the class name to AcSummayCell.

Comment: Thanks Mani you have saved me.. i was doing that for file owner.Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

follow this... for custom tableview cell
 [UITableViewCell Space between Title and Subtitle -iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158028/uitableviewcell-space-between-title-and-subtitle-ios/18160065#18160065)

or this awesome tutorial

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks mayank i'm already following that tutorial, but did not get the thing "connect the outlet pointing to your custom cell"..when i right click on my custom cell in nib to connect with outlate it does not show my outlates to connect with?

Answer (score 1):

follow this code properly....

AudioCell.h

```
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AudioCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *artistLabel;
...


@end
```

AudioCell.m

```
#import "AudioCell.h"

@implementation AudioCell

@synthesize titleLabel = _titleLabel, artistLabel = _artistLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Now implement this code in your class at the TableView Data Source....

```
#import "AudioCell.h"
.....
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AudioCell";

AudioCell *cell = (AudioCell *)[self.audioFeedTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (AudioCell *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [cell configurePlayerButton];
}

// Configure the cell..


cell.titleLabel.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.artistLabel.text = [commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
....

return cell;
}
```

Link your custom TableViewCell with the subClass by the same way....
[image]

Comment: I'm doing as same way.

Answer (score 0):

I see your mistakes:

You don't specify Cell class and reuse identifier in your customCell
Create custom cell `AcSummaryCell:UITableViewCell` first then choose class for tableCell in the nib Cell. Also assign cell identifier in NIB. If correct , your cell must display
`AcSummaryCell-SimpleTableCell` in Object field.

For hookup to IBOutlet, just choose editor(show assistant editor) -> then choose Automatic-`AcSummaryCell.h` -> then drag and hookup IBOutlet you want.