# Custom TableView Cell not getting configured

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a Class MTTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
The init method in the class is as follows: 
Notice that I set the backgroundcolor to purple.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self)
    {
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    }
    return self;

   // return [self initMVTableViewCellWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier cellColor:nil];
}
```

I call the following method from the delegate of the tableview

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString* identifier = @"one";
        [self.tableView registerClass:[MVTTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];

        MVTTableViewCell *cell = [[MVTTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = [self->datasource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        return cell;



    }
```

However I do not see any change in the color of the table view cells.
What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try moving your call to register class to your viewDidLoad method, and instead of alloc/initing the cell, try dequeueing one from the table. By registering the cell's class for reuse, you're preparing it for recycling by the table. Note: be sure that the cell id that you register is the same as the one that you access in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[MVTTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"one"];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"one";

    MVTTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self->datasource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not on a machine where I can test this an I can't seem to remember the cell call structure in this case (it's late :)) But I would check to see if maybe a different init is being called, otherwise, try setting the background color in cellFor... itself just to troubleshoot. Try setting it on the contentView of the cell as well.

Comment: Tried it. Didnt work. I am using alloc/init just as a way to test. dequeuing didnt work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The following code fixed it :                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor= [UIColor purpleColor];                      So I guess the white color of the text label was blocking the purple color of the contentView.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to change the background color of my cell i usually use this:

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self)
   {
     [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
   }
    return self;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this... for custom tableview cell

[UITableViewCell Space between Title and Subtitle -iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158028/uitableviewcell-space-between-title-and-subtitle-ios/18160065#18160065)

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/