# Custom UITableViewCell Class Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've read quite a few tutorials online about how to create a custom cell subclass, but I'm still a little confused. When I try to follow the instructions found in this question, I end up with errors that the tableView is not a valid property for the object of ViewController.

I've created a new subclass of `UITableViewCell`, called `CustomBookClass`. I've hooked up the properties with my `CustomBookClass.h` file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomBookCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bookImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateAdded;

@end
```

I then go into my `ViewController.m` file to edit the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.tableView.delegate = self];
[self.tableView.dataSource=self];

[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomBookCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Custom    
Cell"];

}
```

I get an error on the tableView, saying the property doesn't exist, even though in the `ViewController.h` file, I'm including the table view.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,   
UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious here, as this is my first time trying this. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524331/custom-tableview-cell-not-getting-configured/18525759#18525759

Comment: Have you actually created a `UITableView` property anywhere, and initialized it ? I do not see it anywhere in the code. Also `self.tableView` is valid property of `UITableViewController` and *not* `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` does not have that property. Even if you assign the Delegate and DataSource protocols to it. There are a couple of things you can do however.

1. Link the table view to the `ViewController` yourself. That means, create a property/outlet called `tableView`.
2. Inherit from `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.

Both should work.

Edit: Oh and the lines:

```
[self.tableView.delegate = self];
[self.tableView.dataSource=self];
```

don't make sense. They should be either:

1. `self.tableView.delegate = self;` and `self.tableView.dataSource = self;`
2. Or `[self.tableView setDelegate:self];` and `[self.tableView setDataSource:self]`

with 1 being preferred. (Edit: option #2 was actually incorrect code, my bad.)

Comment: Just to make sure I have it straight... create a property for the tableView in the ViewController.h file, tie it to the table in the storyboard, and then use the code as I have it? (Again, sorry if this is obvious...)

Comment: Precisely and no need to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

No  need to set delegate and datasource in TableViewCell class

simple make a property and synthesize your table view item

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bookImage;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookTitle;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateAdded;
```

now import your cell class in your tableView controller class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {

        //If you are using xib for representing your UI then add a nib file.

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.bookTitle.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.bookImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.dateAdded.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

for more detail check this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)